# setting image attribute of an object

Tags: c#

Is it possible to set an image as an attribute of an object in a user defined class? Like in the class below-could I have an image of each person as an attribute and include it in the constructor? I've done lots of googling on this and havent found anything, I have a feeling I'm missing soemthing pretty obvious but I cant seem to figure out how to even import an image class- total beginner to this.

```
 public class Person
 {
    String fName, lName;

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        this.fName = firstName;
        this.lName = lastName;
    }
```

Comment: attribute != property in C#

Comment: @BojanKomazec In a general sense I would personally consider a property an attribute of the parent type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

top of your sourcefile add

```
using System.Drawing;
```

in your class add

```
Person
{
   Image myImage;
```

In your constructor, simply include an Image. Image works very similar to string.

```
public Person(string firstName, string lastName, Image profilePic)
{
  // your stuff
   this.myImage = profilePic;
}
```

Comment: DGibbs used get; set; which is more effective than what I did. :) Just thought I added to your own code

Comment: its a pleasure. Give a thumbs up to the other guys here as well. DGibbs used get set which is how it should be done out there. Tigran proposed using base64 for your images. It is more complicated, but thats the proper way of using images in your class. You might want to try getting a good book on #.   c# in a nutshell by alhabari is just about the very best out there, You can procure it on the internet for yourself :)

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to put an image like an `Attribute`, you may think to
use `base64` rapresentation of image like a string value of that attribute.

I *never* did something like this, so don't know if there is some length restriction in 
`CLR` on this. You should try it yourself.

Even thow this seems like "cool idea", I would recommend just having external resource, and

- or have resource name like attribute
- or link to IO data (file, DB field.. ).

Answer (score 1):

Yep:

```
 public class Person
 {
    public string fName { get; set; }
    public string lName { get; set; }
    public Image image { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, Image image)
    {
        this.fName = firstName;
        this.lName = lastName;
        this.image = image;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you need. You can always add String property with image URL and use it in browser, form or any other application that needs to display it. 
My suggestion that you save on some location and know exact URL to it. URL should be public and accessible by anyone who needs to read it.

**EDIT: missed code**

```
public class Person
 {
    String fName, lName, imageUrl;

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, string imageUrl)
    {
        this.fName = firstName;
        this.lName = lastName;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is possible, your code would look like:

```
public class Person
{
    String fName, lName;
    Image pImage;

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, Image img)
    {
        this.fName = firstName;
        this.lName = lastName;
        this.pImage = img;
    }
}
```